# Finding Big O of 1/n + 1/n+2 ... 1/n'

Tags: asymptotics

The number of computations of an algorithm is $n'm\sum_{x=0}^{n'-m} 1/(m+x)$. What is the complexity of the algorithm ?

Thanx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty 1/m$ is known as the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). Its partial sums are the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_n := \sum_{m=1}^n 1/m$. It is known that $H_n = \ln n + O(1)$. In fact, there are much more accurate asymptotic estimates, such as $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + O(1/n)$, where $\gamma$ is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

In your case, you have a more general type of sum of the form
$$
\sum_{m=a}^b \frac{1}{m} = H_b - H_{a-1} = \ln \frac{b}{a} + O\left(\frac{1}{a}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanx Yuval. Could you please give me a reference where there is the definition of $H_b -H_{a-1}$ ?

Comment: It's just the difference of two harmonic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Selah, instead of asking for more references and definitions, you can just use the fact that for the n values n ≤ k < 2n, we have $1/{2n} ≤ 1/k ≤ 1/n$. So the sum of $1/k$ for n ≤ k < 2n is between 1/2 and 1.

Not nearly as nice as Yuval's result, but it should be more than good enough to solve your problem.